# Magento addAttributeToFilter, filter by attribute text

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I want all products by a certain manufacturer, lets say "Nike" (a user can enter a string here). But when using:

```
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 'Nike');
```

it doesnt work, because instead of "Nike" the manufacturer id is expected. Is there an easy way to get the id from the name or is there a way i can filter with only having name and not id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the id by label and then perform addField to filter on the collection

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("manufacturer");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {

     $manufacturer_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId("Nike");
}

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',$manufacturer_id);
```

Comment: The answer to solve my problem to filter based on dropdown value. +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to firstly get the `attribute id` and then use in filter

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("manufacturer");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $attr_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId("Nike"); // your_attribute_label
}
$products = $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', $attr_id)->getData();
echo "<pre>";print_r($products);
```

Comment: perfect, but other, similar answer was a bit earlier, so the other one flagged.